# Highlight words in pandas dataframe for excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like

```
| c1                  | c2                       |
|:--------------------|:------------------------:|
| this has value as a | this has different value |
```

What I want is to highlight the word `different` from c2 using colour as yellow and write this dataframe to excel as this is a new vocabulary for c2 compared to c1. Finding a difference in c2 is not important.

But how to highlight only a single or some words in a cell (not the entire cell)?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Using pandas [styling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Building-Styles) functionality you can add styling(colors) to your data frame.

Comment: In above link there are many examples and change your string comparison logic in it.

Comment: Please update the answer with a proper working example. The answer is too broad and vague. There is no documentation of exactly what I want (colour only a word in a sentence).

Comment: You want me write logic for comparing 2 string and highlight words in it?

Comment: Just write the code to highlight the word `different` from the above df. I mean just do the formatting for `different`. No need to perform the comparison.